# Difference between "bis auf", "bisher", and "bis zu"?

Tags: word-choice

My understanding is that they all mean "up to." But could they mean "up to in different contexts, some in time, for instance, and other with regards to space?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Bis zu

is equivalent to `up to` or `as far as`.

> Der Baum wird bis zu 3m hoch.

Next,

> Bisher

is used in a temporal context and can be translated with `until now` or `so far`:

> Ich habe bisher noch keine Wohnung.

Finally,

> Bis auf

can be used for `except for`

> Bis auf Heinz habe ich alle angerufen.

**EDIT**

See @Em1's comment for additional cases.

Comment: Dir fehlt noch: "Er ist bis auf 5 Meter rangekommen." und "Das Stadion war bis auf den letzten Platz ausverkauft."

Comment: @Em1 True, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It is not the appropriate way to differentiate between those three words and collocates, respectively. You forget "bis in", "bis nach", "bislang", ...

First of all, depending on its usage the word *bis* is a different type of word: conjunction, adverb or preposition.

Depending on what you're saying a preposition like *auf*, *zu*, *nach* etc. is following *bis*.

1. Temporal or spatially termination. *Bis* can be followed by a preposition.

   - temporal:

     - *Bis gestern*; *bis nächste Woche*
     - *Bis zum 15. August*; *bis um 3 Uhr*
     - *Bis einschließlich 15. August*
     - *Bis zur letzten Sekunde*
     - *Bis auf weiteres*
     - *Bis nach Mitternacht*
   - spatially:

     - *Bis hierher*; *bis (nach) unten*
     - *Bis in die weite Ferne*
     - *Bis zum Gebäude*; *bis zur Universität*
     - *Bis auf die nacke Haut*
     - *Bis (nach) Deutschland*

   Which preposition you have to use depends on the context. A preposition can change the meaning completely.

   > Die Party ging bis Mitternacht.
   >
   > Die Party ging bis nach Mitternacht.

   The former sentence indicates that the party ended at midnight, while the latter sentence doesn't determine the end of party exactly. It's just saying that the party last until an indefinite time after midnight.
2. *Including* (*Einschließlich*) - Always with *auf*

   > Das Stadion war bis auf den letzten Platz ausverkauft.
   >
   > Wir beschlossen, die Frist bis auf die letzte Minute auszunutzen.
3. *Except for* (*Mit Ausnahme von*) - Always with *auf*

   > Bis auf drei (Frauen) waren alle Anwesenden männlich.
4. Limitation, when placed before numbers. Everything below that number is included. - Preposition *zu* can be used or left out.

   > Nicht geeignet für Kinder bis zu drei Jahren.
   >
   > Nicht geeignet für Kinder bis drei Jahre.

The word *bisher*, however, is a compound of *bis* and *her* and determine a time range from an indefinite point in the past until now. You can replace *bisher* with *bis jetzt*, *bis zum jetzigen Zeitpunkt* without changing the meaning. If the time span is quite long (i.e. days, months or years) you can also replace *bisher* with *bis heute*.

> Er ist bisher noch nie zu spät nach Hause gekommen.
>
> Ich habe bisher noch nichts von ihm gehört.

---

I left out the conjunction since it is not important to your question.