# Is there a difference between 'bis' and 'bis an'

Tags: word-choice

There is a good list of bis phrases [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5464/difference-between-bis-auf-bisher-and-bis-zu), but it doesn't include 'bis an'.

> Eine noble Kriegerin bis an ihr Ende,...

"A noble warrior until her end...". Is the 'an' needed here? Can the phrase be written without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Bis" usually only works with time.

> bis Montag, bis nächstes Jahr, bis dann

It does work on it's own in a locational or abstract sense too... but not very often.

> Mit diesem Zug fahre ich bis Berlin und dann nehme ich das Auto.

Usually you will have to use an extra preposition. That can be "zu", "an", "in", etc

> Geradeaus bis zur Kreuzung.

That wouldn't work without "zu"... I would be asking "Bis die Kreuzung WAS?".
In fact, I have difficulty to "feel" the case that goes with "bis". "Bis den", "bis dem"... both sound awkward to me. That is not to say that there isn't a case... only that it is almost never used in combination with an article.

EDIT:

Since the answer seemed to not have been clear enough... no I'd say just assume that you can never leave out the preposition after "bis" if there is one.

Comment: bis (zur) zu der Kreuzung, bis (zum) zu dem Ende

Comment: @Vogel612... what's your point?

Comment: "almost never". all compound articles count as articles in my eyes..

Comment: @Vogel612... any backup on that? Besides... I would still ardently disagree. That would make things unnecessarily complicated from an explaining point of view.. they' contractions, no more no less

Comment: backup? take the random question on which way to go: "Bis zum Ende der Straße, und dann links[...]" Also put more focus on "in my eyes"... In fact I think it makes explaining easier, if you modify it a bit.

Comment: So you're basically saying that "zum" is an article that only exists in "dative singular" and "fürs" is an article that only has an "accusative singular" form but "nebens" doesn't exist. Also, if you consider those as articles then you'll have to say "bis" can stand with the article alone IF the article is part of a group of articles that are contractions of prepositions and articles... why not just say prepositions then and be done with it. I really can't seem to understand how this view (which you can of course have) is making anything easier

Comment: No. What I mean is, that you should look at zu dem instead of zum to analyze the sentence from the viewpoint of a learner. This shows that, when bis is used with a preposition you will (probably) never find a case nominative noun as "target"

Comment: „Bis Berlin“ empfinde ich auch als Verkürzung.

Comment: The question linked in the question already discusses `bis zu`.  Your answer doesn't appear to explain `bis an`, except for including it in a list without further detail.

Comment: @BenVoigt ... there is nothing to explain, other than what I said for the general "bis". I have added a summary now that says it more directly.

Comment: Haven't really checked this, but intuitively, I would say that anytime the fitting preposition is "nach" (in the exact target sense, not in the "after" sense), you can drop it.

Answer (score 2):

in this case „an ihr Ende“ is a time range (until her death). This sentence can't stand without the „an“, it would be plain wrong.
If you have to rewrite the sentence, you could write „bis zum Ende ihrer Tage“, here again the „zum“ is needed.

Answer (score 0):

*Bis* wird benötigt eine weitere Präposition, auch wenn es manchmal ohne verwandt wird (*bis ein Uhr* statt *bis um ein Uhr*).

- * Eine noble Kriegerin bis ihr Ende

ist falsch. Neben

- Eine noble Kriegerin bis an ihr Ende

ist auch

- Eine noble Kriegerin bis zu ihrem Ende

möglich.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it can not be written without a preposition (here `an`) in your case .

A case when `bis` would not come with such a preposition is, when it is part of an adverbial phrase in context of time ([Temporaladverbial / Adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbiale_Bestimmung#Semantische_Klassenbildung)).
Examples:

> - Ich bleibe **bis morgen**.
> - Das Event geht noch **bis Sonntag**.
> - Daran wird sich **bis 2020** nichts ändern.
> - ...**bis dass der Tod euch scheidet**.
> - Fahr' geradeaus **bis du die Kreuzung erreichst**.